# using primefaces in liferay 6.1

Tags: primefaces, liferay

I have created a sample portlet using primefaces bridge in lifeary. The main functionality is create/edit/delete in some tables. How is it possible to split code of on page to more.
To be more specific I want when I click on a record to go to another xthml page in which I will load the data from selected record

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get portlet context and the for example user information

```
System.out.println("Getting user info");
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
User user = PortalUtil.getUser(portletRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Much concise way of doing this is

```
PortalRequest request = LiferayFacesContext.getPortalRequest();
User user = PoralUtil.getUser(portletRequest);
```

or to get the currently logged in user, use the following code

```
LiferayFacesContext.getInstance().getUser();
```

should give you the Liferay user object for the currently logged in user.